# Android HTTPUrlConnection response returns garbage

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

Here is my code for header the inputstream

```
mResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

mError = mResponseCode != 200 && mResponseCode != 201 && mResponseCode != 202;

if (mError) {
    inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();
} else {
    inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
}
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

String inputLine;
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    builder.append(inputLine);

resultStr = builder.toString();
```

but the string returns garbage values like this "���������������}"

The response header includes `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` so I tried adding

```
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

but didn't help.

its working perfectly on postman so I know it not something wrong with the service.

Can someone offer some assistance?

Comment: Do you mean the returned data?

Comment: What is the content encoding that you get from he response ?

Comment: If you mean the transer-encoding its chunked and the Content-Type is application/json; charset=UTF-8

Comment: yes, the returned data! but it's more like an encoding problem.

Comment: @Ali thanks man. Apparently it was zipped.

Comment: @NaveenDissanayake keep in mind that if it has `Conent-Encoding: compressed` set, the library should autohandle compression.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Thats the thing, the response didn't have a content encoding. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: One more thing, if resp code >= 400, getErrorStream(), else getInputStream() :)

Comment: @BNK yeah normally that would be my procedure too but this is a special service :D

Answer (score 3):

Some service try to compress data they produce with the help of header parameters like:

> [Content-Encoding](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11): [SomeKindOfEncoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)

To disable this feature try to set the accept encoding:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
```

If you would like to save some transfer data on the mobile phone use the following:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); //optional forcing gzip
//...
inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
//rest of the code
```

Comment: yep, it looks like zip to me. At least OP could confirm if there's a compression header or whether this answer works